# Rails self recursive issues with Parents and Children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

I am rying to add a subsidiary to a company. SO I will go the company, and the select from a list 1 or more subsidiaries and save. So I am NOT saving a company to a subsidiary (as it seems its the case below), but rather adding a subsidiary to the company,

So then this example below makes no sence to me! I mean how do I save the subsidiary to a company?

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates   :name, presence: true
    has_many :subsidiaries, :class_name => "Company", :foreign_key => "parent_company_id"
    belongs_to :parent_company, :class_name => "Company",
end
```

**Could you please show me how the save would look in my controller, as Im sure this is where Im going wrong.**

Current my problem is that the way I save Im saving the supposed to be subsidiary as the parent_id, so basicly its reversed:

here I select a subsidiary from a list:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:parent_company_id, @companies, :id, :name, :include_blank => true, :multiple => true) %>
```

Just to be clear what currently happens:

1. I open company A
2. I select company B as a subsidiary and save
3. I look at companies and see that B has a subsidiary A (wrong!!) and it makes sense because its parent_id was set to A, but actually I need to set its "subsidiary_id"

Comment: You're looking at this from the wrong end.  Each company stores its parent's id.  The parents do not store a list of their child companies.  This has nothing to do with the fact that the parents and children happen to be in the same table, or recursion.

Comment: Ok, so its correct as it stands? Just me representing or saving it wrong then? But still, one would think calling company.subsidiaries would should its subsidiaries, not parents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way of doing this:

```
<p>Parent Company</p>
<%= f.collection_select :parent_company_id, ... %>
```

You go around to all the child company records and set their parent company.  Afterwards, you take a look at `@parent.subsidiaries` for your list.

If you want to do this all from the parent company's form, you'll have to do some trickery with javascript and `fields_for` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, or maybe with a bunch of checkboxes -- the record that is actually changed is the *child* record, not the parent record.

Watching [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) may help.

Comment: But I want to add it as its subsidiary, not its parent

Comment: Ok, I got it working. So now Im not saving the parent Id, but rather setting the parentid of the selected option to the id of the model in view.